# How does CloudSponge import your iCloud contacts?

Tags: authentication, icloud, contacts, privacy, cloudsponge

CloudSponge has an option to import your iCloud contacts. How does this work? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the CardDav protocol to read a list of the contacts in your iCloud account. Requests are authenticated using HTTP Basic Auth in the header.

[CloudSponge never saves your private information](https://www.cloudsponge.com/promise/). Your credentials and contacts stay in memory only long enough to return your address book.

For maximum security, you can even create an app-specific password for your iCloud account.